# java replace ' with \'

Tags: java, mysql, replace

I'm working with mySQL. It can not handle if `'` is in the String that is being added to the database.

I tried:

```
replaceAll("'","\\'")
```

and

```
replaceAll("'","\'")
```

Any ideas how I would go about replacing `'` with `\'`?

Comment: I think your real problem is dynamically building SQL queries at runtime instead of using a `PreparedStatement`. Please show more of your code where you insert into the database, most likely it's no manual escaping is necessary at all.

Comment: I do not know what PreparedStatement are. I'm just creating a simple webpage.

Comment: Please check out JB Nizet's answers below, he gives sample code plus a link to the relevant section of the JDBC tutorial. This is important -- `PreparedStatement` almost always result in safer, cleaner and faster code.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds good. I just browsed trough it. I'm bookmarking it, and will be reading up on later. Thanks man

Comment: Pay close attention to what has been said here. If you're doing what it sounds like, your website is wide open to being hacked by SQL injection attacks. It's possible for a knowledgeable (ab)user to run arbitrary SQL against your database - including grabbing potentially sensitive details and/or deleting all your data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash twice, once for the string processing engine and once for the regex engine:

```
replaceAll("'","\\\\'")
```

**Caveat:** While this answers the question about how to insert a backslash into a string, it certainly should not be used in an attempt to thwart SQL injection attacks.

To clarify: Imagine someone submits a string where the apostrophe *is already escaped*. This regex would then lead to the apostrophe being *unescaped* (because now the backslash would become escaped). So actually you'd need this regex to escape an apostrophe only if preceded by an even number of backslashes. This means

```
replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\\\\\)*)'", "$1\\\\'")
```

This is rapidly becoming as unmaintainable as it looks, and it still doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: No offense, this obviously answers the question, but I think it only works around the actual problem :)

Comment: @PhilippReichart: I agree, and in my opinion JB Nizet's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use String replacements to handle this. Instead, use a prepared statement and thus let the JDBC driver escape the parameters for you:

```
String sql = "select a.foo from a where a.bar = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, aStringWhichMightContainQuotes);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

This is the proper way to have database-independent, robust code, that is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. And it also make it more efficient if you execute the same query several times with different parameters.

See the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more information.